# Marker info erratic in KML layer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-maps-markers

I am working on loading KML files into a map using Google Maps API v3. The KML loads fine and the markers are seen. But the marker info (pop-up when the marker is clicked) never shows up in a consistent manner. A few work some times, some others don't. This is really peculiar. To see the page, check-

http://www.sobitabraham.com/teawap/NEW_kml.html

The KML file is here-

https://sites.google.com/site/teawapdata/home/kml-files/TEAWAP.kml

The KML file is 990 KB in size, so it is not some file size ceiling problem. It could have something to with the caching of KML, I am not sure. The KML file was exported from Google Earth.

The frustrating thing is that this marker behavior is erratic, the error is not consistent. This problem is seen even when I paste the URL of the KML file into maps.google.com. Any help in sorting this out will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Every marker and feature I clicked on correctly displayed the info window.

Comment: Thanks for checking out the file. Could you please tell me what platform/browser you are using? I am using Mozilla Firefox 12.0 on Windows and the problem still persists. Could it be something related to the browser? What other factors should I look at...?

Comment: I've checked it in both Chrome (v23.0.1262) and FireFox (v15.0.1) on Windows. You should check your error consoles for JavaScript errors, but that's all I can think of.

Comment: I reproduced the problem by toggling the layer.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I'm still at square one...This is **really** strange. Should I try and use Fusion Tables to ensure a more predictable performance? Or is that going too far... @geocodezip